# How to add new user to Spring Security at runtime

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, persistence, registration

I save users in a DB table via Hibernate and I am using Spring Security to authenticate:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

And this works perfectly, but there is a point - user is loaded during server start. I need to write method RegisterUser(User user) that add new user to Spring Security in runtime. This method should focus only on this task. I dont know how to start to implement this feature so thanks for any advices! ;)

Ofc User have fields like login, password, role string etc etc...

Please do not post solutions with Spring MVC. This system is RESTful app using Spring Web Boost and Spring Security Boost in version 4.0.x

Comment: There are Spring Security + Hibernate examples out there, give it a search. For example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/

Comment: please did you find a solution for your problem could you post the code ?

Answer (score 17):

You probably want to store your users in a database and not in memory, if they are registering :)

1. Create the [authorities](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/GrantedAuthority.html) for the user

   ```
   List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
   authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
   ```
2. Instantiate the user (with a class implementing [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html))

   ```
   UserDetails user = new User("user@example.com", passwordEncoder.encode("s3cr3t"), authorities);
   ```
3. Save the user somewhere useful. The [JdbcUserDetailsManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html) can save a user to a database easily.

   ```
   userDetailsManager.createUser(user);
   ```
4. Create a [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html)

   ```
   Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
   ```
5. Add the Authentication to the [SecurityContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html)

   ```
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
   ```

Comment: Where do I create this user and SecurityContext?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda SecurityContext is created by Spring. You would want to create the user in your registration logic, after getting info from the user (such as their desired username and password), probably in a service layer used by a controller

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using the spring provided /oauth/token URL, is that not correct? Where can I access the username and password provided to this url?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) for user creation.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

usage:

```java
User user = new User();
userRepository.save(user);
```

How to authenticate above user:

1. Create custom `AuthenticationProvider`, select user data from your DB and authenticate:

```java
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upAuth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        final String name = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();

        final String password = (String) upAuth.getCredentials();

        final String storedPassword = userRepository.findByName(name).map(User::getPassword)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException("illegal id or passowrd"));

        if (Objects.equals(password, "") || !Objects.equals(password, storedPassword)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("illegal id or passowrd");
        }

        final Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            principal, authentication.getCredentials(),
            Collections.emptyList());
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());

        return result;
    }
    ...
```

2. Configure with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for using above `AuthenticationProvider`:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        http.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
}
```

refs:

- [Spring Security Architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/)
- [complete code sample](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/en32244745)

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out. Where is `UserRepository` constructed?

Comment: UserRepository is constructed automatically by Spring Boot. [Core concepts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) section and [Spring Data JPA Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-data-jpa-repositories) section may help you.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to add authority to current user:

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_NEWUSERROLE'); 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(),
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials(),
            authorities)
        );
```