# Add users dynamically in Spring Java

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

This code I use to add users from my database that can authenticate but the problem this code is executed once , I want to have users that register how can I achieve that ?
I have this solution [How to adding new user to Spring Security in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244745/how-to-adding-new-user-to-spring-security-in-runtime) but I coudn't add it to my actual code please help.
this is my code

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            for (UsersEntity user : userRepository.findAll())
                if (user.getUsername() != null && user.getPassword() != null)
                    auth.
                            inMemoryAuthentication()
                            .passwordEncoder(UsersEntity.ENCODE_PASS)
                            .withUser(user.getUsername()).password(user.getPassword())
                            .roles("USER");
        }


        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
                throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set another `authenticationProvider`.

```
@Autowired
private MyAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

Simply implement your own `MyAuthenticationProvider` that asks your `UserRepository` for each login attempt. Or another way would be to simply use basic jdbc:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
  .usersByUsernameQuery(
  "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
  .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
  "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
 }
```

...of course, you would need to set your own queries there.

Comment: I used the first solution for simplicity :) thank you

Comment: Good choice, since that has the advantage of keeping the whole "Find user" logic in one place, the `UserRepository`. The JDBC solution tends to duplicate it, which makes it harder to maintain if something changes.

Comment: hi does jdbc solution update new roles dynamically ?

Comment: Not sure, but honestly, I doubt it. When should it do so? It would have to guess - or send dozens of role requests to the database.